# Apache2 Debian OwnCloud 9 not found after OC Update 8.2 to 9

Tags: linux, debian, apache-http-server, owncloud

I've got following problem:

After updating my OwnCloud from 8.2.2 to 9, it maybe crashed my Apache2 Config. So when I try to open myserver.com/owncloud it says:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /var/www/owncloud/index.php was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at myserver.com Port 80

it's confusing because in Apache confs-available / confs-enabled there is a file for owncloud:

```
Alias /owncloud "/var/www/owncloud/"

<Directory /var/www/owncloud>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All

    <IfModule mod_dav.c>
        Dav off
    </IfModule>

    SetEnv HOME /var/www/owncloud
    SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www/owncloud
</Directory>
```

somebody has a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIX:**

I fixed it by editing the .htaccess in the /var/www/owncloud directory

Just add

```
RewriteBase /owncloud
```

above

```
 RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

this fixed it for me

See:
https://github.com/owncloud/core/pull/23029

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that this also happens on fresh installs of OwnCloud 9 on Ubuntu & Debian. Did not have time to troubleshoot this further this week but I suspect something wrong in the .htaccess file in the /var/www/owncloud dir.

Hopefully someone can pinpoint the issue and post it here.

Comment: See : https://github.com/owncloud/updater/issues/270

Comment: OK, this fix works for me.

Edit /var/www/owncloud/.htaccess and just below the `RewriteEngine on` line, add `RewriteBase /owncloud`.

I suspect this will get fixed in a point release of owncloud 9 shortly.

Comment: works, line #41 in .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

The above fix worked for me. However my upgrade was still in maintenance mode from the upgrade that probably caused this. I had to go edit the config.php to turn off maintenance mode.

> $ sudo nano /var/www/owncloud/config/config.php

I also then restarted apache2

> $ sudo service apache2 restart

then I could finish the upgrade and all looks well now. Thanks again for the tip!